# Sails.js and New Relic (browser integration)

Tags: sails.js, newrelic

I'm trying to get new relic browser integration working with Sails.js
Getting new relic working at applicatin level is quite simple:

```
var newrelic = require('newrelic');
// Start sails and pass it command line arguments
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

in app.js

However to get the browser stuff working you need to call `newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader()` at the beginning of the html head.

I've tried various things, such as adding newrelic to global, (`global.newrelic`) but that seems to disappear, adding it to local.js in config, and passing it in to lift as a config override, however that doesn't seem to work either (I'm probably passing it in wrong)

So does anyone have any idea how I can get the `newrelic` variable from the orginal app.js to the layout file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So turns out when you run `sails lift` on the command line it doesn't actually use the app.js file.
To use that you have to do `node app.js`.
My app.js now looks like this;

```
global.newrelic = require('newrelic');
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

then in `layout.ejs` you can add

```
<%- global.newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader() %>
```

Putting stuff in the global might not be the best solution, however whenever I put it into the sails.config the object got messed up :(

Comment: You saved me from pulling my hairs!

Answer (score 0):

@cosmorogers First of all, your answer is a perfectly valid way to do this.  To clarify, you're creating a new global variable called `newrelic` whether you attach it to `global` or not- i.e. `newrelic=require('newrelic');` does the same thing.

> So turns out when you run sails lift on the command line it doesn't actually use the app.js file

Indeed- and as you mentioned, you can always lift sails with `node app.js` instead.

Some additional info/commentary here: http://willricketts.com/using-newrelic-with-sails-js/#comment-1551000708